# Issue while trying to validation encrypted password in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

**Creation of database record**

```
$encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter();
        
$password = base64_encode($encrypter->encrypt("12345aA!"));

$data = [
    "email_address" => "email@gmail.com",
    "password" => $password,
    "user_id" => 1
];
$query = "insert into tblusers(user_id, email_address, password)";
$query = $query . "Values(:user_id,, :email_address, :password)";
$this->db->query($query, $data);
$this->db->table("tblusers")->insert($data);
```

**Validation of Password with database saved record**

```
$encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter();

$model = new UserModel();            
$user = $model->where("email_address", "email@gmail.com")->first();
echo $encrypter->decrypt($user["password"]);
```

**Approach 2 used but same error message comes**

```
$encrypted_password = "Py02s1SOIlI/p6sSzqDCqgR81wXuXSSdrA5R8wnLs/SQDig0A2hXjvcn4TfYYaa+Xoq4sMt4gJF5Krec8U8G8fKcrrXsSxbSG3BS";
echo $encrypter->decrypt($encrypted_password);
```

**Error Message**

Decrypting: authentication failed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're applying [`base64_encode(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) after encrypting your *'raw password'*.

```php
// ...
$password = base64_encode($encrypter->encrypt("12345aA!"));
// ...
```

But then, you **forget** to apply [`base64_decode(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) before decrypting the stored *'password hash'*.

```php
// ...
echo $encrypter->decrypt($user["password"]);
// ...
```

##### Solution:

*Validation of Password with database saved record*

```php
$model = new UserModel();
$user = $model->where("email_address", "email@gmail.com")->first();

try {
    $decryptedPassword = \Config\Services::encrypter()
        ->decrypt(base64_decode($user["password"]));

    echo $decryptedPassword;

} catch (\CodeIgniter\Encryption\Exceptions\EncryptionException $encryptionException) {
    log_message("error", $encryptionException->getMessage());

}
```

##### Extra Note(s):

I would recommend you use PHP's built-in secure hashing algorithms instead for this scenario.
[`password_hash(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
[`password_verify(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: still not working but password_hash worked perfectly